# Cluster data based on distance threshold

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I would like to delete a data on which is 10cm close from the previous data.

This is what i have but it takes a large computational time because my dataset is very huge

```
for i in range(len(data)):
     for j in range(i, len(data)):
          if (i == j):
               continue
          elif np.sqrt((data[i, 0]-data[j, 0])**2 + (data[i, 1]-data[i, 1])**2) <= 0.1:
               data[j, 0] = np.nan
data = data[~np.isnan(data).any(axis=1)]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: That seemed like a typo - `data[i, 1]-data[i, 1])**2`. Should had been : `data[i, 1]-data[j, 1])**2` instead it seems. Correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach using a [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree

def cluster_data_KDTree(a, thr=0.1):
    t = KDTree(a)
    mask = np.ones(a.shape[:1], bool)
    idx = 0
    nxt = 1
    while nxt:
        mask[t.query_ball_point(a[idx], thr)] = False
        nxt = mask[idx:].argmax()
        mask[idx] = True
        idx += nxt
    return a[mask]
```

Borrowing @Divakar's test case we see that this delivers another `100x` speedup on top of the `400x` Divakar reports. Compared to OP we extrapolate a ridiculous `40,000x`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.rand(10000,2)
data2 = data1.copy()

from timeit import timeit
kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=10)

print(timeit("cluster_data_KDTree(data1)", **kwds))
print(timeit("cluster_data_pdist_v1(data2)", **kwds))

np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.rand(10000,2)
data2 = data1.copy()

out1 = cluster_data_KDTree(data1, thr=0.1)
out2 = cluster_data_pdist_v1(data2, dist_thresh = 0.1)
print(np.allclose(out1, out2))
```

Sample output:

```
0.05073001119308174
5.646531613077968
True
```

It turns out that this test case happens to be quite favorable to my approach because there are very few clusters and thus very few iterations.

If we drastically increase the number of clusters to about `3800` by changing the threshold to `0.01` `KDTree` still wins but the speedup is reduced from `100x` to `15x`:

```
0.33647687803022563
5.28947562398389
True
```

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. The occasions I can come out ahead of your stuff are precious few.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) with one-loop -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def cluster_data_pdist_v1(a, dist_thresh = 0.1):
    d = pdist(a)
    mask = d<=dist_thresh

    n = len(a)
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum() ))
    start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
    idx_out = np.zeros(mask.sum(), dtype=int) # use np.empty for bit more speedup
    cur_start = 0
    for iterID,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(start, stop)):
        if iterID not in idx_out[:cur_start]:
            rm_idx = np.flatnonzero(mask[i:j])+iterID+1
            L = len(rm_idx)
            idx_out[cur_start:cur_start+L] = rm_idx
            cur_start += L

    return np.delete(a, idx_out[:cur_start], axis=0)
```

#### Benchmarking

Original approach -

```
def cluster_data_org(data, dist_thresh = 0.1):
    for i in range(len(data)):
         for j in range(i, len(data)):
              if (i == j):
                   continue
              elif np.sqrt((data[i, 0]-data[j, 0])**2 +
                           (data[i, 1]-data[j, 1])**2) <= 0.1:
                   data[j, 0] = np.nan
    return data[~np.isnan(data).any(axis=1)]
```

Runtime test, verification on random data in the range : `[0,1)` with `10,000` points -

```
In [207]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: data1 = np.random.rand(10000,2)
     ...: data2 = data1.copy()
     ...: 
     ...: out1 = cluster_data_org(data1, dist_thresh = 0.1)
     ...: out2 = cluster_data_pdist_v1(data2, dist_thresh = 0.1)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
True

In [208]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: data1 = np.random.rand(10000,2)
     ...: data2 = data1.copy()

In [209]: %timeit cluster_data_org(data1, dist_thresh = 0.1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 50s per loop

In [210]: %timeit cluster_data_pdist_v1(data2, dist_thresh = 0.1)
1 loop, best of 3: 287 ms per loop
```

Around **`400x`** speedup for such a setup!